# postman environment variables not working?

Tags: node.js, api, postman, postman-collection-runner

[Not getting data with environment variable but when putting with hardcoded url: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/store it be getting data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TukzF.png)

[Get data with hardcoded url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEIYk.png)

What something went wrong ? please advise

Comment: I order to get response you must pass a request along with the server URL whether you have hosted it remotely or running on your local computer(can be accessed by http://127.0.0.1/<port_number> or http://localhost/<port_number>


Here is a link it may help you much: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/

Comment: Does it work if you remove the trailing / from the URL in the variable?

Answer (score 2):

At the end of your environment variables, you have an "/" who don't have to be here, if you concat it, it give you `http://localhost:3000**//**api/v1/store`